# Cast attribute is used for foreign key query instead of native type

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, uuid, laravel-6

We are using binary UUIDs our mysql database and cast them to string on the model. This was working brilliantly for us in laravel 5.7, but it's not working as expected in 6.x.

We can create the records and related records with the binary uuid just fine. However, we can't read the relation, it turns up empty due to a mismatch between the cast value and what is in the database.

You can see the `post` record being created with a binary `id` and foreign key `user_id`

```
[2019-11-27 05:39:57] local.INFO: insert into `posts` (`title`, `user_id`, `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  
[2019-11-27 05:39:57] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 'Veniam error quod minima. Error laborum voluptatum sunt exercitationem dolor. Quis qui ipsa occaecati iste minus dolor omnis.',
  1 => '=��K�WE3��wQ
��',
  2 => '�7n��kLS�T$�L�',
  3 => '2019-11-27 05:39:57',
  4 => '2019-11-27 05:39:57',
```

But if you try to query the relationship, eg. `$user->posts` the cast value of `user_id` is used.

```
[2019-11-27 05:39:57] local.INFO: select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` = ? and `posts`.`user_id` is not null  
[2019-11-27 05:39:57] local.INFO: array (
  0 => '3d93a84b-fb57-4533-96ab-1c77510ab4e0',
)
```

and thus no records are found.

Is this a bug in laravel, it should be using the native type for the select query instead of the cast value, shouldn't it?

The methods on the model are essentially:

Casting

```
    protected function castAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->uuidColumns()) && !empty($value)) {

                return $this->resolveUuid()->fromBytes($value)->toString();
        }

        return parent::castAttribute($key, $value);
    }
```

and a boot method that creates the UUID when the model is created.

```
    public static function bootGeneratesUuid(): void
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            /* @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static $model */
            $uuid = $model->resolveUuid();
            foreach ($model->uuidColumns() as $item) {
                if (isset($model->attributes[$item]) && !is_null($model->attributes[$item])) {
                    /* @var \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid $uuid */
                    $uuid = $uuid->fromString(strtolower($model->attributes[$item]));
                }
                $model->attributes[$item] = $model->hasCast($item, 'uuid') ? $uuid->getBytes() : $uuid->toString();
            }
        });
    }
```

I've made a detailed reproduction here 
https://github.com/edeis53/laravel6-uuid-issue/blob/master/README.md